# Creating a JavaFX proxy causes a UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: javafx, clojure

I'm trying to write a JavaFX app in Clojure. As a simple test, I wanted to try to just launch a Hello World. To extend `Application`, I decided to try using `proxy` instead of `:gen-class`. I wanted to be able to create a bare-bones function that creates an `Application`, instead of requiring me to write the boilerplate every time.

The simple example I came up with was:

```
(let [^Application app
      (proxy [Application] []
        (start [self stage] (println "Hello World")))]

  (Application/launch ^Class (.getClass app)
                      (into-array String [])))
```

The problem is, this causes an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

> UnsupportedOperationException start  chat.graphics_tests.javafx_wrapper.proxy$javafx.application.Application$ff19274a.start (:-1)

It seems like it can't find the `start` method that I implemented. My first thought was that the arguments to `start` were wrong. They seem correct though. The first argument it receives is "`this`", then the primary stage. I tried different numbers of arguments though, and I still get the same error. According to the docs:

> If a method fn is not provided for an interface method, an
>   UnsupportedOperationException will be thrown should it be
>   called.

Which further my this suspicion.

The errors quite vague. Does anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: I just read that `proxy` can't be used here since `Application/launch` requires a named class. Guess I'm using `:gen-class`.

Answer (score 0):

When writing [proxy](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/proxy) class definitions in Clojure you do not need the explicit `self` parameter in the method signature.  The current instance will be implicitly bound to `this` which you will be able to use inside the methods.

Therefore your proxy call should look like this:

```
  (proxy [Application] []
    (start [stage] (println "Hello World")))
```

Comment: Nope, same error. As I said, I had tried many different combinations of arguments. And, as I mentioned in the comment under my answer, I read afterward that `proxy` can't be used here. I decided to leave the question up in case anyone else is trying to use `proxy`. I suspect they'll get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

[This appears to be because `Application/launch` requires a named class, which `proxy` doesn't create.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664317/3000206) (see the comment at the bottom of the answer. I'm trusting @Sam here).

I ended up caving and using `:gen-class`, and got it working after some fiddling.